# How to debug this PHP contact form sender?

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have this php sender file below, I think something goes wrong with when trying to send an email. I verify everything seem looking good but the form still not working. Checking but find nothing. What can I try next?

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $subject = trim($_POST["subject"]);
        $number = trim($_POST["number"]);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name)  OR empty($subject)  OR empty($number)  OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Vérifiez que tous les champs soient bien remplis et que l'email soit sans erreur.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "severinyeboue@gmail.com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "Nouveau message de $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "subject:\n$subject\n";
        $email_content .= "number:\n$number\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "De: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Merci! Votre message nous est bien parvenu !";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "L'envoi du mail a échoué, veuillez réessayer SVP.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "Vérifiez que tous les champs soient bien remplis et que l'email soit sans erreur.";
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors ? Do the `mail()` returns true ?

Comment: If you are not getting any errors, it could be that the issue is with mailserver not the php code. Even if the mail() returns true it does't mean that the email is sent - 

**From official php doc** [https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php]
Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.
It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.